# Objective C - Can I use NSSet to setEnabled:NO to a set of NSButtons?

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton, nsset

I have written a timer application that passes a speechTime from an IBAction and counts down to 0.  There are five distinct speechTimes, and a toggler button that will stop the speech time countdown. I would like to be able to disable the buttons that are not the IBAction pressed while the timer is counting down (to prevent resetting the speechTime).

I currently have several [speechButton setEnable:NO] and [... setEnable:YES] calls, and they all work the way I expect; but i suspect it's poor memory management and makes for *really* nasty looking code. I would like to implement something like an NSSet of all the buttons, and enable / disable them using only one method so that i end up with [buttons disable]/[buttons enable].

I played around with something like this:

TimerViewController.h

```
@implement TimerViewController{
NSButton *buttonA, *buttonB, *buttonC; 
}
@property (retain, readonly) NSSet *hijackableButtons;
-(void)disableButtons
@end
```

TimerViewController.m

```
...
@synthesize hijackableButtons;
-(void)init{
//blah blah blah
hijackableButtons = [NSSet setWithObjects:*buttonA,*buttonB,*buttonC,nil];
}
//...

-(void)disableButtons{
for (id buttons in hijackableButtons){
    if (buttons isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]){
        [buttons setEnabled:NO];
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `IBOutletCollection` which is defined for this situation.

Have a look a this [example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html).

Comment: This is a really good suggestion! unfortunately, iOS4 implemented this, but it has yet to be implemented for Mac OS X development apparently.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820804/looking-for-a-way-to-use-an-nsarray-as-an-outlet-for-a-bunch-of-buttons/4820925#4820925

Answer (score 1):

See `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` in the `NSSet` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NSResponder check for the `-enumarateObjectUsingBlock:` I was not convince about Block until I used a method like that one.

BUT for your code, this is your problem

```
hijackableButtons = [NSSet setWithObjects:*buttonA,*buttonB,*buttonC,nil];
```

rewrite it like this

```
hijackableButtons = [NSSet setWithObjects:buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, nil];
```

Reomove the `*` that are not needed here.

---

I'm assuming that your are created in the `bla bla` section of your init method.
If they are IBOutlet, this code don't belong in your init method.