# naming a number of NSButtons

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have written some terrible code but it works. Is there a better way to write this? _decade.x are NSButtons.

```
int baseDecade = 1940;
NSString *title;
int currentDecade = 0;

- (IBAction)nameDecade:(id)sender {

    currentDecade = baseDecade;
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)currentDecade];
    _decade1.stringValue = title;

    currentDecade = currentDecade +10;
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)currentDecade];
    _decade2.stringValue = title;

    currentDecade = currentDecade +10;
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)currentDecade];
    _decade3.stringValue = title;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you can put your buttons in a single [`IBOutletCollection`](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/) in interface builder, or in an `NSArray` if you create your buttons through code. With that outlet collection / array in hand, you can use a loop to reference `_decadeN` by their index in the collection:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *decadeButtons;
...
for (int i = 0 ; i != decadeButtons.count ; i++) {
    UIButton * decade = decadeButtons[i];
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)(baseDecade+10*i)];
    decade.stringValue = title;
}
```

**Edit:** [OSX does not support `IBOutletCollection`s yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820925/335858), so you would need to put `_decadeN` buttons in an array namually:

```
// I am using the new array literal syntax; using arrayWithObjects will work too.
NSArray *decadeButtons = @[_decade1, _decade2, _decade3];
// Use the same loop as above:
for (int i = 0 ; i != decadeButtons.count ; i++) {
    UIButton * decade = decadeButtons[i];
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)(baseDecade+10*i)];
    decade.stringValue = title;
}
```

Comment: I think that IBOutletCollection is for iOS only. I am looking for an OSX solution. I really want to get this into a "for" loop as you have suggested (+1). I just can't figure out how to address distinct buttons..

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Oops, I didn't realize it's NSButtons, not UIButtons (I guess I did not read the question carefully enough). Please take a look at the update.

Comment: woohoo. brilliant. Thank you so much. late middle age is a pain sometimes :)